# Sign & Unsigned Char is not working in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer 5th Edition I saw this
[image]

when I tried to use it---
[image]

At this time it didn't work, but the program's output did give a weird symbol, but signed is totally blank And also they give some warnings when I tried to compile it. But C++ primer and so many webs said it should work... So I don't think they give the wrong information did I do something wrong?
I am newbie btw :)

[image]

Comment: the "weird symbol" is the character with the value `255`. the second example results `c` overflowing to `0`, which, as a character, prints nothing at all.

Comment: The text in the image is incorrect; `c2` has implementation-defined value (not undefined)

Comment: @stefan Then why did C++ Primer said signed should print undefined and unsigned should print 255. Does they mean something different?

Comment: if it is 255 when i used unsigned then why can't I see 255, and why this weird symbol :)

Comment: The book didn't say anything about printing

Comment: If you want to print the numerical value (in the sense that a value of `10` will print a pair of characters with value `1` and `0`)  of a `char` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`) it is necessary to convert it to an `int`, and print that.    Output streams format `char` types differently (so an `unsigned` char may have a numeric value of `255`, but when output it appears as a graphic symbol - which symbol depends on the character set supported by your implementation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But C++ primer ... said it should work

No it doesn't. The quote from C++ primer doesn't use `std::cout` at all. The output that you see doesn't contradict with what the  book says.

> So I don't think they give the wrong information

No<sup>1</sup>.

> did I do something wrong?

It seems that you've possibly misunderstood what the value of a character means, or possibly misunderstood how character streams work.

Character types are integer types (but not all integer types are character types). The values of `unsigned char` are 0..255 (on systems where size of byte is 8 bits). Each<sup>2</sup> of those values represent some textual symbol. The mapping from a set of values to a set of symbols is called a "character set" or "character encoding".

`std::cout` is a character stream. `<<` is stream insertion operator. When you insert a character into a stream, the behaviour is not to show the numerical value. Instead, the behaviour to show the symbol that the value is mapped to<sup>3</sup> in the character set that your system uses. In this case, it appears that the value 255 is mapped to whatever strange symbol you saw on the screen.

If you wish to print the numerical value of a character, what you can do is convert to a non-character integer type and insert that to the character stream:

```
int i = c;
std::cout << i;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, there's no wrong information regarding your confusion. The quote is a bit inaccurate and outdated in case of `c2`. Before C++20, the value was "implementation defined" rather than "undefined". Since C++20, the value is actually defined, and the value is 0 which is the null terminator character that signifies end of a string. If you try to print this character, you'll see no output.

<sup>2</sup> This was bit of a lie for simplicity's sake. Some characters are not visible symbols. For example, there is the null terminator charter as well as other control characters. The situation becomes even more complex in the case of variable width encodings such as the ubiquitous Unicode, where symbols may consist of a sequence of several `char`. In such encoding, and individual `char` cannot necessarily be interpreted correctly without other `char` that are part of such sequence.

<sup>3</sup> And this behaviour should feel natural once you grok the purpose of character types. Consider following program:

```
unsigned char c = 'a';
std::cout << c;
```

It would be highly confusing if the output would be a number that is the value of the character (such as 97 which may be the value of the symbol 'a' on the system) rather than the symbol 'a'.

---

For extra meditation, think about what this program might print (and feel free to try it out):

```
char c = 57;
std::cout << c << '\n';

int i = c;
std::cout << i << '\n';

c = '9';
std::cout << c << '\n';

i = c;
std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: I couldn't understand some parts but i understand that i should have used int instead of char :) i am newbie i can't understand that much :( can ya tell me a place where I can learn the basics of C++ well to understand ur answer :)

Comment: @rafid100 Footnotes 1 and 2 are pedantic stuff that you can probably ignore as a beginner until they become relevant. This is probably a good place to start learning: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303

Comment: The nul terminator is a C string convention; output functions that traffic in C strings treat it as the end of the string. That doesn't mean that `std::cout << char(0)` has to produce no output -- that inserter does not treat its argument as a C style string, but as a plain old character. Yes, the character with code point 0 typically doesn't have a textual representation, but in that regard it's no different from the character with code point 1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed. It would be the same for other control characters, would it not?

Comment: @eerorika -- some control characters have well-defined "visible" effects: `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and `\v` all map to control characters but show up in the output. (The reason for putting "visible" in quotes is that `\a` is actually auditory, but it is noticeable, nonetheless). See [lex.ccon], and, in particular, the table of Escape Sequences at the end of that section.

Comment: @PeteBecker I had thought of `\r\n\t\v` as "whitespace", rather than control charceters. But I suppose that's what they are.

Comment: Re: "control character" vs. "whitespace" -- it's a matter of perspective. From the language perspective, those are whitespace; from the device perspective they're control characters.

Comment: @eerorika did ya mean if the char c is 0 when signed it will print the weird symbol sorry i couldnt test it because i am in Android device right now

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the behavior of the `<<` operator on the `char` type and the character stream `cout`. Note, the `<<` is known as *formatted output* means it does some implicit formatting.

We can say that the **value** of a variable is not the same as its **representation** in certain contexts. For example:

```
int main() {
    bool t = true;
    std::cout << t << std::endl; // Prints 1, not "true"
}
```

Think of it this way, why would we need `char` if it would still behave like a number when printed, why not to use `int` or `unsigned`? In essence, we have different types so to have different behaviors which can be deduced from these types.

So, the underlying numeric value of a `char` is probably not what we looking for, when we print one.

Check this for example:

```
int main() {
    unsigned char c = -1;
    int i = c;
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // Prints 255
}
```

If I recall correctly, you're somewhat close in the Primer to the topic of **built-in types conversions**, it will bring in clarity when you'll get to know these rules better. Anyway, I'm sure, you will benefit greatly from looking into this [article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/chars/). Especially the **"Printing chars as integers via type casting"** part.